# How can I create portable/rss comments feed on website in java or jquery?

Tags: java, jquery, rss

I am trying to create a comments feed from my site that can be embedded by any user into their site or blog. For example if you look at this test
http://www.skill-guru.com/test/81/core-spring-3.0-certification-mock

It has test comments. Registered users can comment and we are adding a feature where Facebook users can add in comments as well.
If the creator of this test wants to show comments on his own website, do I need to create a rss feed for the comments which he can plug into his blog/site?
Or I should be exposing the comments via JSON API which kind of becomes technical for the test creator.

Comment: I have use the Rome RSS with very positive results

Comment: Look like Rome RSS will solve the problem. Will look into it

Comment: I tried ROME rss as per your suggestion and that looks like will solve the problem. If you put that as an answer, I would have accepted it

Comment: It's fine, you are welcome mate

Answer (score 0):

Don't recreate the wheel by inventing your own json structure that developers should parse. It is hard enough keeping up with RSS and its variants / Atom. Ask yourself what you would do when the json format changes in backward incompatible ways (for a valid reason). Its just not worth it. There are also many widgets / readers for RSS / ATOM. Some developers have made entire products by just reading these feeds and presenting them in smart ways. You can piggy back on such work if you choose standard feed formats.

Stick to the standards. Your life will be much easier.

Comment: So you are suggesting I should create the comments in the standard feed format which can be read by any other rss reader ?

Comment: Yes. Its much easier if you take this route. You can use the ATOM protocol if you need more flexibility.